# 2136 (0858) (RC2136): MQRC_MULTIPLE_REASONS

Tags: ibm-mq

We are trying to delete one or more queue from a MQ Channel that was previously configured. DEletion was successful. When we ran the application code we got the below error code/description:-

2136 (0858) (RC2136): MQRC_MULTIPLE_REASONS
Explanation
An MQOPEN, MQPUT or MQPUT1 call was issued to open a distribution list or put a message to a distribution list, but the result of the call was not the same for all of the destinations in the list. One of the following applies:
•   The call succeeded for some of the destinations but not others. The completion code is MQCC_WARNING in this case.
•   The call failed for all of the destinations, but for differing reasons. The completion code is MQCC_FAILED in this case.
This reason code occurs in the following environments: AIX®, HP-UX, i5/OS™, Solaris, Windows, plus WebSphere® MQ clients connected to these systems.
Completion Code
MQCC_WARNING or MQCC_FAILED

Programmer response
Examine the MQRR response records to identify the destinations for which the call failed, and the reason for the failure. Ensure that sufficient response records are provided by the application on the call to enable the error(s) to be determined. For the MQPUT1 call, the response records must be specified using the MQOD structure, and not the MQPMO structure.

https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.amqzao.doc/fm13300_.htm

http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?p=6475&sid=eb310522e0959bb828917836dfa550ea

How can we solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

This reason code suggests that your application is doing an MQPUT to multiple queues at once by providing the names of them in the MQOR structure hung off the MQOD structure.

You say that you deleted some queues and then after that deletion was done your application started to report this error. This suggests that you have deleted at least one of the queues that your application was previously referring to, but not all of the queues that it was using. So some of the reason codes were MQRC_NONE and some of the reason codes were MQRC_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND because you deleted them, hence the MQRC_MULTIPLE_REASONS. As your text in your question indicates, to see all the individual reason codes, you need to look in the MQRR structure returned to your application.

Perhaps you could post your application code, or at least the part where the queue names are set, so we can advise further.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not only delete the queue but also remove it from the distribution list.